# Creating Dynamic Textbox , but code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started learning java script.I am trying to make Dynamic text box but the my code is not working . Can someone help me in rectifying my mistake??

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script language="javascript">

     function add(){
         var text=document.createElement('input');
         var add=document.getElementById("Myform");
         text.setAttribute("type","text");
         text.setAttribute("name","BookName");
         add.appendChild(text);
     }
 </script>
 <form action="new1.php" id="Myform"> 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="javascript:add();"/>      <br/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The text box disappears before I can do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input type as button or other wise it will submit the form.You want the submit button means you have to add one more button for dynamic action.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="javascript:add();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need stop submit like this:

```js
 function add(){
 var text=document.createElement('input');
 var add=document.getElementById("Myform");
 text.setAttribute("type","text");
 text.setAttribute("name","BookName");
 add.appendChild(text);
 }
```

```html
 <form action="new1.php" id="Myform" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();"> 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="javascript:add();"/>      <br/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tz0vkAGGHKpPfRDy1dhV?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="new1.php" id="Myform"> 
 <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="add();"/>      <br/>

</form>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
function add(){
 var text=document.createElement('input');
 var add=document.getElementById("Myform");
 text.setAttribute("type","text");
 text.setAttribute("name","BookName");
 add.appendChild(text);
 }
```